# Not Equal (ne) and OR not returning correct results in Mongomapper scopes

Tags: ruby, mongodb, model, scope, mongomapper

I can't chain these two scopes together in Mongomapper using an OR:

```
scope :comment_is_nil, where(:comment => nil)
scope :post_not_blank, where(:post.ne => "")
```

It should return model objects where the comment is not nil, OR the post is not blank.

This doesn't work:

```
Model.where("$or" => [{:comment_is_nil, :post_not_blank])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining scopes is an **and** operation so `M.comment_is_nil.post_not_blank` won't work as you know. [MongoDB's **or** syntax](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) looks like this:

```
Model.where(
    :$or => [
        { :comment => nil },
        { :post.ne => ''  }
    ]
)
```

So you need to give it an array of individual conditions by manually expanding the scopes.